# Sketch the solid of integration Q.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

I am given $\int_{0}^{2} \int_{-\sqrt{y^2 + 1}}^{\sqrt{y^2 + 1}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1 -x^2 + y^2}} dzdxdy$, I think the upper portion of the first limit is a hyperboloid of one sheet but isnt the solid the starting shape which would just be 1 ? how would i sketch this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $z$ varies from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2+y^2}$. When $z$ is equal to this upper limit, by squaring both sides we have:
$$
z^2=1-x^2+y^2
$$
that is
$$
y^2=z^2+x^2-1
$$
which is a hyperboloid of one sheet with its principal axis being the $y$ axis (the one that makes the hyperboloid a rotation surface over it)